# How would I call a specific value from a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: arrays, loops

Okay, so this is just a small example of something similar I am doing in my own program I am creating for an online class. The only difference is the output of each array will be inputted by user in a different fields instead of having the answer predetermined by the programmer.

In this case after the user numbers are outputted, I want to create a button (which I know how to do, sorry if this is too theoretical right now) which will specific values and output them in a different field.

For example... for aryNumbers[0][0] (Which in my program would be a name) I would call out aryNumbers[0][1] to aryNumbers[0][4] ...so in this case 10, 76, 23.(these numbers would be test scores)

```
int[ ][ ] aryNumbers = new int[2][4];

aryNumbers[0][0] = 34;
aryNumbers[0][1] = 10;
aryNumbers[0][2] = 76;
aryNumbers[0][3] = 23;

aryNumbers[1][0] = 11;
aryNumbers[1][0] = 30;
aryNumbers[1][0] = 56;
aryNumbers[1][0] = 65;

aryNumbers[2][0] = 34;
aryNumbers[2][0] = 13;
aryNumbers[2][0] = 23;
aryNumbers[2][0] = 18;

int rows = 2;
int columns = 4;

int i, j;

for (i=0; i < rows ; i++) {

for (j=0; j < columns ; j++) {

System.out.print( aryNumbers[ i ][ j ] + " " );

}

System.out.println( "" );

}
```

Only it would call out all values for the entire list of names and their corresponding test scores.

Aka...

```
ary..[0][1]
ary..[0][2]
ary..[0][3]

ary..[1][1]
ary..[1][2]
ary..[1][3]

ary..[1][1]
ary..[1][2]
ary..[1][3]
```

This is my first time working with multi-dimensional arrays..

Comment: I'm still unclear on the question here. You seem to want to skip the first (or zeroth) item in the inner array for each value in the outer array and print the resulting values. Are you asking how to do it? Because you've mostly written it but haven't explained the problem you are getting.

Comment: If you just changed "for(j=0..." to "for(j=1...", does that not achieve your aim?

Comment: Hmm...I would want to skip the 'zeroth' since is a name, and not an integer like the following arrays are. Once I've learn't how to isolate the arrays [1][1] through [2][3] I will be finding the average of those numbers.

Comment: O.o well...that did not occur to me...I'll have to try that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `for(j=0...` to `for(j=1...` to skip the zeroth element of the inner array.